# Matplot lib : scalling of the axes on bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using following script to plot cluster populations using two lists contained x and y data

```
# calculate clusters using encore method
cluster = encore.cluster(u, select="all", superposition=False, method=encore.DBSCAN(eps=1))

# make list of population of each cluster;
cluster_sizes= [len(c) for c in cluster.clusters]
# make list of the cluster number;
cluster_numbers=[x+1 for x in range(0,len(cluster_sizes))]

# plot data
plt.bar(cluster_numbers, cluster_sizes)
plt.title('Cluster Populations')
plt.grid(True)
#plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.savefig(f'clusters.png')
plt.close()
```

The problem that sometimes on the resulted bar plot the values are ranged by 0.5 along both X and Y (see the enclosed picture as the example). How I could plot only integers along the both axes? In my example graph the X should be scalled from 0 to 20 (avoiding 0.5 spacings) and the Y from 0 to 18 (thus [image]avoiding these unused 0.5 spacings)

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community where we review code that is working as expected that you have written. This question is off-topic because the code is not working as expected. As indicated on your [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252654/python-stacking-images) please read the [Code Review Guidelines for Asking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Use `plt.xticks` - https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html.

One may to `xticks` `np.arange(len(cluster.clusters))` as an argument

And for `yticks` it works in a same fashion -if you pass `np.arange(int(max(cluster_sizes)))`, there will be integer ticks along the `y`-axis

Comment: Thank you very much for this info! Generally it may work very good for a particular graph, but could not be applied in the script producing many different bar plots (with broad range of values on X and Y). For example, in the case of many bars on the same plot, the values of X tend to overlap. By contrast, if there is only one bar (1 cluster) it  looks like a big square, then an individual bar :-) I tried to add step argument for both xticks and yticks to customize values along both axes but it also could not be applied for many different graphs ...  are there other possibilities?

Comment: @MaîtreRenard I am not aware of any adaptive ways for formatting, the more flexible thing is `major formatter` https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/custom_ticker1.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-custom-ticker1-py

Comment: Decent answer for Stack Overflow, we don't answer `how to` questions on Code Review, the code has to be working as expected.